# nodejs synchonous child process in REST API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, exec

i have an API in nodejs that returns the current IP configuration. the weird thing is, the console logs the correct settings but the res.json ends up empty. what am i missing?!?

```
var exec = require('exec-sync');

app.get('/current', function(req, res) {
  var c=a=[];
  var ret=exec('ifconfig eth0| grep inet\\ ');
  ret.split('\n').forEach( function(str) {
    if (str) {
      a=str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ').split(' ');
      c[a[1].split(":")[0]]=a[1].split(":")[1];
      c[a[3].split(":")[0]]=a[3].split(":")[1];
    }
  });
  ret=exec('route -n|grep ^0');
  ret.split('\n').forEach( function(str) {
    if (str) {
      a=str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ').split(' ');
      c['gw']=a[1];
    }
  });
  console.log(c);
  res.json(c);
});
```

example CONSOLE output:

```
[ addr: '192.168.1.2',
  mask: '255.255.255.0,
  gw: '192.168.2.1' ]
```

while the json in my angular page built with {{ settings | json }} shows up as [].

any ideas??

Comment: Do you see data inside HTTP response body if you look at it with FireBug or another dev tool? How do you handle request in AngularJS?

Comment: no, the dataset is empty. i use this:
`
    $http.get('/current'). then(
      function(ret) {
        $scope.network = ret.data;
      },
      function(ret) { console.log("Network loading error"); }
    );
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it's easier than it looks. changing from 
`var c=a=[];`
to
`var c=a={};`
solves the problem. wonderful how you can look at it a 100 times and never see it, then the next day it's so obvious ...